# convert a list to dictionary by using formkeys with different values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

can I have a list that I use formkeys to convert it into a dictionary and the values of the dictionary be their indexes of the list?

for example my list is  `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]`

and if I use formkeys, I want it will be `{"a" :0 , "b" :1 , "c" :2 , "d" :3 , "e" :4  }`

could you tell me how can I do it?

or if you know another way that it's order is less than this way (in python), please tell me.

Comment: Do you mean `fromkeys`, derived from "from keys"?

Comment: @NTh For the answers which helped you, don't forget to upvote them by clicking the up arrow icon next to them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suppose `lst` = `['a', 'b', 'c' ...]`:

```
dict = {a: b for b,a in enumerate(lst)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dict.fromkeys` method is meant to assign the same value to each of the key in a given sequence, which is not the case if you want a differing index as a value for each key.

Instead, you can `enumerate` the list and reverse the generated index-value tuples to construct a new dict:

```
dict(map(reversed, enumerate(lst)))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/MiserableOrdinaryEmulator

Answer (score 0):

```
{y:x for x,y in enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by using [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) along with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) as:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

>>> dict(zip(lst,count()))
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4}
```

You can also use [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-range) to skip the import of *itertools* library. For example:

```
>>> dict(zip(lst,range(len(lst))))
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4}
```